# validate login with response json

Tags: objective-c, json, authentication, response, nsurlconnection

I want to perform segue if login response is

Login response:

> {"Login":[{"userid":"12","name":"(abc)"}]}

How can I validate it.?

Below is my code for fetching response.

```
-(IBAction)loginbutton:(id)sender {
    NSString *post = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"email==%@&pass==%@",self->email.text,self->passwrd.text];
    NSData *postData = [post dataUsingEncoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding allowLossyConversion:YES];
    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"URL"];
    NSMutableURLRequest *theRequest = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
    [theRequest setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
    [theRequest setHTTPBody:postData];
    NSURLResponse *response;
    NSError *error;
    NSData *urlData = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:theRequest returningResponse:&response error:&error];
    NSString *str=[[NSString alloc]initWithData:urlData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]; NSLog(@"Login response: is %@",str); //getting response
}
```

Comment: Parse the JSON response and look at whatever values you need to validate. There are countless examples of parsing JSON in Objective-C.

Comment: @rmaddy i have mentioned my response in the question and i want to validate that to proceed login .

Comment: Right. And I'm telling you what you have to do. You need to parse the JSON and get the values you need from it. Make an attempt to parse the JSON using the countless existing examples you can find. Then update your question as needed once you get that far.

Answer (score 0):

```
NSString *post = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"email==%@&pass==%@",self->email.text,self->passwrd.text];
NSData *postData = [post dataUsingEncoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding allowLossyConversion:YES];
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"URL"];
NSMutableURLRequest *theRequest = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
[theRequest setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
[theRequest setHTTPBody:postData];
NSURLResponse *response;
NSError *error;
NSData *urlData = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:theRequest returningResponse:&response error:&error];
NSDictionary *jsondictionary = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:urlData options: NSJSONReadingMutableContainers error: &error];
NSLog(@"%@", jsondictionary);
```

Output will be :

```
{
     Login: [{
     userid: 12,
     name: (abc)
     }]
     }
```

To get user details Please use below code:

```
NSArray *userdetail = [jsondictionary objectForKey:@"Login"];
NSString *userID = [[userdetail firstObject]objectForKey:@"userid"];
NSLog(@"%@",userID);//12
NSString *userName = [[userdetail firstObject]objectForKey:@"name"];
NSLog(@"%@",userName);//(abc)
```

Comment: value in name is null Login =     (
                   {
            name = "(null)";
            userid = 17;
        }
    );
}

Comment: during the user creation you didn't send username . Server side issue . If you want to validate [[userdetail firstObject]objectForKey:@"name"] ! = nil || [[userdetail firstObject]objectForKey:@"name"] != null